# Find all table names in database which has a column which contains a certain value, MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I want to find all the table names where i have a certain value, like:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema WHERE column_name = "MyColumnName" AND MyColumnName = "value";
```

I have problem searching for a value in the column, how should i write the last part..

```
AND MyColumnName = "value";
```

..?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in 1 query. Your first query should identify all the tables that you need to query. You then need to query all the tables and you can either do this by hand or write a dynamic sql script to generate the table queries. I'm not going to do this for you since this looks like coursework (it's surprising how often this comes up - must be the time of year so I'm sure you can find further help if you search SO)

Comment: Thanks for input, I will try to divide the query. Actually i am working with a project and have no database course until further in my education, that's why it is hard for me to interpret answers from similar questions :P